# In FastReport4, How to align 3 memo lines vertically where if the 2nd memo line is empty the remaining 2 can be align togather automatically?

Tags: delphi, vertical-alignment, delphi-xe3, fastreport

Using FastReport4 in Delphi XE3.

I have 3 Memo fields as it shown in Fig-1, I want if one of the fields is empty they can automatically align vertically, but my problem is lets say if memo2 is empty I get what's in Fig-2 an empty space between memo1 and memo3, I've tried stretching, shifting modes with no use, I want it to be as Fig-3, So any idea how to do it?

Thanks.

[image: Fig-1]
[image: Fig-2]
[image: Fig-3]

Comment: Using band and set the stretching would be the usual to solve this

Comment: Is [the documentation about multiline text](http://goo.gl/TRjzo) any help?

Comment: nope, I've tried that way, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must examine that is the Memo empty or not using below code in Delphi in before print event:

```
if TfrxMemoView(frxReport.FindObject('Memo2')).Text = '' then
  TfrxMemoView(frxReport.FindObject('Memo3')).Top := TfrxMemoView(frxReport.FindObject('Memo2')).Top;
```

Comment: Great I knew it was easy but I didn't think of it that way!! thanks

Comment: I would be tempted to just put all the available text in a single multi-line memo `Memo1.text := GetAllNonEmptyLinesFrom(Array);`